# How do I disable the quick actions floating toolbar in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

[Adobe Acrobat's May 2019 update](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/whats-new.html#Commentingexperienceimprovements) added a "quick actions" floating toolbar to highlight, underline, strikethrough, and copy text whenever you make a selection:

[image: Adobe Acrobat quick actions on text selection]

I find this extremely irritating and distracting, so how can I disable it?

Comment: You can't. See [The new floating toolbar for commenting actions... | Adobe Community](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2622821)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like now its possible with a new update. Followed the link from @DavidPostill, there is a new comment.

Uncheck the following option:

Goto Edit --> Preferences --> General --> Show Quick actions on text selection